# Logical errors while simulating master-page concept in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, user-controls

I'm trying to simulate the ASP.Net master-page concept (Layout in MVC) on WPF `Window`s.

I have a `CustomWindow` class that specifies some behaviors for this sort of `Window`s:

```
public class CustomWindow : Window
{
    //...
}
```

And `MasterWindowBase`; a `CustomWindow` that takes some sort of my `UserControl`s to be the window content (via style):

```
public abstract class MasterWindowBase : CustomWindow
{
    public MasterWindowBase(MyUserControlBase content)
    {
        ContentUserControl = content;
        Style = Application.Current.FindResource("MasterWindowStyle") as Style;
    }

    #region ContentUserControl Property
    public MyUserControlBase ContentUserControl
    {
        get { return (MyUserControlBase)GetValue(ContentUserControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentUserControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentUserControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ContentUserControl", typeof(MyUserControlBase), typeof(MasterWindowBase));
    #endregion
}
```

The style defined in application resources:

```
        <Style x:Key="MasterWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MasterWindowBase}">
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="This is a master window"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ContentUserControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MasterWindowBase}}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And `MasterWindow`; a generic window used to create an instance of `MasterWindowBase` with the specified `UserControl` type:

```
public class MasterWindow<TMyUserControlBase>
    : MasterWindowBase
    where TMyUserControlBase : MyUserControlBase, new()
{
    public MasterWindow() : base(new TMyUserControlBase()) { }
}
```

Now for the first `Window.Show`, everything works perfectly, but then I caught two logical errors:

1. When I close the Window and show a new instance of it with a different `UserControl`, it loads the content of the first-shown `MasterWindow`.
2. When I show a new instance of `MasterWindow` either with the same `UserControl` or with a different one without closing the currently-showing window(s), it clears the content of all the currently-showing `MasterWindow` instances, and loads the content of the first-shown `MasterWindow` in the new instance.

*Note that I can't use the `Template` property inside the `MasterWindowStyle` style because the style is actually based on `CustomWindow`'s style (in the real project) which already use the `Template` property*.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of observed behavior is you try to set *Content* of your window in Style. Because it's not a template - WPF will create a tree with your UserControl only once. Then when you apply this style again and again - the same visual tree (with the same, first, UserControl) is reused every time (and of course one control cannot be used in different parents - so it gets removed from where it is hosted now and moved to the window you apply style to).

Long story short - you just should not setting Content via Style in WPF. To fix your immediate problem, you can just set *ContentTemplate* property instead of Content, and wrap what you have in DataTemplate (leaving everything else the same). This will fix it, because for templates new visual tree is created every time.

Here is yet another way to fix it, still using Content property, however it looks like kind of a hack and I'd better void doing this (though still works):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Grid x:Shared="False" x:Key="myControl">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="This is a master window"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ContentUserControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MasterWindowBase}}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <Style x:Key="MasterWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MasterWindowBase}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="myControl" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here you define your visual tree in resources with x:Shared="False" attribute. This attribute means every time this resource is referenced - new instance will be created (by default - same instance is reused). Then you reference this resource inside your Style.

Comment: Great solutions. After I read your answer, I've also found that I can just add the `x:Shared="False"` attribute to the style, and still use the `Content` property.. all of 'em work. Thanks!